# How to find the derivative of the commutator map?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

> Let $f : \mbox{GL}_n(\mathbb R) \to \mbox{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$ be defined by $$f(X) = K X K^{-1} X^{-1}$$ where $K$ is invertible matrix. How to find derivative of $f$?

Can I use here product rule of differentiation as follows?

$$f'(X)=KX'K^{-1}X^{-1}+KXK^{-1}(X^{-1})'$$

Am I correct? Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: It would be a fourth order tensor. I hope someone can help you

Comment: You could try computing the Fréchet derivative by expanding $f(X+H)$ (since $(X+H)^{-1}$ has a power series expansion for $H$ small).

Comment: Which derivative?

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is given by:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X} KXK^{-1}X^{-1} = 
\big((K^{-1}X^{-1})^T\otimes K\big) - \big((X^{-1})^T\otimes KXK^{-1}X^{-1}\big)$$

By using the rules $\partial(\mathbf{X} \mathbf{Y})=(\partial \mathbf{X}) \mathbf{Y}+\mathbf{X}(\partial \mathbf{Y})$,  $\frac{\partial K X}{\partial X}=I\otimes K$ and $\frac{\partial X^{-1}}{\partial X}=-X^{-T}\otimes X^{-1}$

cf. [matrix cook book](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) and  http://www.matrixcalculus.org/

On the other hand, using Gabriels approach gives:

$$\begin{aligned}
f(X+H) &= K(X+H)K^{-1}(X+H)^{-1} \\
&= K(X+H)K^{-1}(I-X^{-1}H)^{-1}X^{-1} \\
&\sim f(X) + KHK^{-1} X^{-1} - KXK^{-1} X^{-1} H X^{-1}
\end{aligned}$$

as the first order Taylor approximation.
Note that both are equivalent because

$$ f(X+H)\sim f(X) + f'(X)\cdot H  $$

and here

$$\begin{aligned} f'(X)\cdot H 
&= \big((K^{-1}X^{-1})^T\otimes K\big) - \big((X^{-1})^T\otimes KXK^{-1}X^{-1}\big)\cdot H
\\ &= KHK^{-1} X^{-1} - KXK^{-1} X^{-1} H X^{-1}
\end{aligned}$$

since in this case the tensor contraction "$\cdot$" works like $(U\otimes V) \cdot H = VHU^T$ where on the RHS it is regular matrix multiplication. This can be seen by looking at the index notation, cf. by answer here [How to reconcile these two Jacobi formuli](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3350932))